# how to update local repo if some one has made change in master repo?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have assigned a project. if someone update code in git repository? would my local repository will update automatically? or i have to do it manually ? what are the commands.

Comment: As berliner answered, you must manually fetch updates. I would avoid `git pull`: use `git fetch` first (at any time: it's always safe), then use `git merge` or `git rebase` *when you are ready*. All `git pull` does is run `git fetch` and then, ready or not, run `git merge` unless you tell it to run `git rebase` instead. Usually `git rebase` is what you want, and the way to *decide* what you want is to look at what `git fetch` fetched! (And, as a side note, there's no requirement for a "master repo": your repository is *yours*, it's up to you how slave-ish to be with it :-) .)

Comment: yeah it worked . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not. I suggest you read some quick start guide on the internet. Like this one http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Here you can find more info https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started

Command to update your local repo is

```
git pull
```